# Cannot use phpmyadmin in XAMPP

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed XAMPP 5.5.30 for Linux(64 bit), which consists of phpmyadmin version 4.5.1. For the first time when I went to phpmyadmin, saw a warning at the bottom saying

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured,
>   some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why. 
>         Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.

I didn't give much attention to that. I tried creating a database. At that time I got another error,

> Table phpmyadmin.pma__tracking doesn't exist in engine

I tried to create the database with the same name again and this time the error was

> Can't create database,database exists

So I refreshed the list of databases and my new database was there and when I clicked on it a "Loading..." loader appeared and it remained there forever. So I tried opening the database in a new tab and this time I got,

> ## 1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__column_info' doesn't exist in engine

After some research I came to know that all these tables (that did not exist) are a part of the phpmyadmin database. So I clicked on it and I got

> Table phpmyadmin.pma__tracking doesn't exist in engine

I am stuck now. As the phpmyadmin database cannot be selected I cannot add or edit any tables in it. Somebody please suggest a way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem with a recent XAMPP release, my suggestion is to roll back to a previous XAMPP version.

That being said, the phpMyAdmin way of fixing it would be:

- Comment out the pma__tracking line in `config.inc.php`. You may also need to comment out the pma__column_info line as well. This will allow you to start phpMyAdmin without the constant error messages.
- Start phpMyAdmin normally
- Run the included `sql/create_tables.sql` (making modifications if needed to match the XAMPP naming scheme)
- Remove the comments in `config.inc.php`

Of course, I can't say whether that will also work for XAMPP.